# Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Angular, estoy usando un servicio para comunicar componentes, pero la comunicación falla

Tags: angular, typescript

Lo que pasa, es que el componente no recibe la información, a pesar de que no encuentro ningún error, no muestra ningún error en consola, simplemente no funciona, no veo ningún error de sintaxis, ni en los imports, intenté crear de nuevo el componente y el servicio, también cambié de ubicación el servicio, probé varias cosas, pero aún no sé que ocurre

**Este es mi servicio:**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormularioService {

  tipodeOperacion = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() {}
}
```

**Este es el componente que manda la información:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormularioService } from '../formulario-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formulario',
  templateUrl: './formulario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formulario.component.css']
})
export class FormularioComponent implements OnInit {

  tipo:string = "ing";
  numero:number = 5;
  descripcion:string;
  valor:number;

  constructor(private formularioService:FormularioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  tipodeOperacion(evento){
    this.tipo = evento.target.value;
  }  

  agregarDato(){
    this.formularioService.tipodeOperacion.emit(this.numero);
  }
}
```

**Este es el componente que recibe la información:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Egresos } from './egresos.model';
import { FormularioService } from '../formulario-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-egresos',
  templateUrl: './egresos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./egresos.component.css']
})
export class EgresosComponent implements OnInit {

  egreso:Egresos[] = [];

  constructor(private formularioService:FormularioService){ 
    this.formularioService.tipodeOperacion.subscribe(
      (tipo:number) => console.log(tipo)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: ¿`EgresosComponent` ya existe cuando se emite un valor o se crea después?

Comment: Tus dos componentes están dentro de el mismo modulo y para estos casos de comunicación entre servicios te recomiendo que uses RXJS, [subject-rxjs-in-angular](https://dev.to/muhammadawaisshaikh/subject-rxjs-in-angular-3dg5)

Comment: Parece que encontré la solución, gracias por sus sugerencias, eso me ayudó